# How to Create Different Topspace in Webview - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

I am currently trying to create a different topSpace(this basically takes out some of the top part of a website and displays the rest) so that when the website loads, the user will have a topSpace of one amount, and when you click on a link in that website, the topSpace can change to a different amount.

Here is my code to show you what I am talking about:

```
class WebViewSports: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var WebViewTst: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Sports"

    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://gunnoracle.com/category/sports/")
    WebViewTst.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)

    let topSpace = -235(takes out the top part of the website)
    let bottomSpace = -2300
    let leftSpace = -40
    let rightSpace = -40
    WebViewTst.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: CGFloat(topSpace), left: CGFloat(leftSpace), bottom: CGFloat(bottomSpace), right: CGFloat(rightSpace))
    WebViewTst.scrollView.bounces = false

    WebViewTst.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    WebViewTst.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0

    WebViewTst.delegate = self

}
```

And when this code runs I get an output of this image:

[image: Image with topspace when loaded]

However, when I click on the link to the article, the header gets chopped off somewhat because of this topSpace, so I was wondering if there was a way to create a different topSpace when a link is pressed.

Here is the output when an article is clicked:

[image: Header chopped off]